# Ag-grid + Angular 2: Dynamically change cellClass of a column in row node

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a requirement where I need to update the background color of cells if the value of a column is different two adjacent rows. Also, I want to be able to do this for some columns only of the grid and not all the columns. (Refer Image)
[image: Column with value change highlighted in red color]

What I did is:

1. I fetched all row nodes in the grid using forEachNode method of the
   gridApi.
2. I compared the value of the column with next value in my
   data array.
3. If the values are different, I update the cellClass property of
   that particular column in the node.

   ```
   this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (node) {
               if (node.rowIndex + 1 < currDetailGridData.length) {
                   if (node.data['ColumnKey'] != currDetailGridData[node.rowIndex + 1]['ColumnKey']) {
                       var nodeToHighlight = node.columnController.gridColumns.find(x => x.colId = 'ColumnKey');
                       nodeToHighlight.colDef.cellClass += 'bgColorRed';
                   }
               }
           });
   ```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. Need your help on identifying, what wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 2):

Might be you are executing it exactly after `rowData` binding inside `onGridReady`.
If so, `grid` need to finalize the data-rendering process, so you can use the hack for it wrapping method in `setTimeout`, **but I do not recommend to use this case.**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(node =>{
        ...
    })
}, 100);
```

Another way is to prepare `columnDef` first, and then use `setColumnDefs` API method to inform the `grid`, **to avoid a loop check.**

And the last one, **I recommend** using `cellClass` binding as `function` in `columnDef`

```
cellClass: this.handleCellClass.bind(this)
...
handleCellClass(params){
    if (params.node.rowIndex + 1 < this.rowData.length) {
        if (params.node.data['...'] != this.rowData[params.node.rowIndex + 1]['...']) 
            return  'bgColorRed';
    }
}
```

Comment: Howdy! I got part of my solution from your answer and upvoted you. Was wondering if you had any thoughts on my current problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146132/dynamic-change-of-cell-color-with-ag-grid