# Dynamic change of cell color with Ag Grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

We are trying to dynamically change the cell color of a column in Ag Grid. Here is the code. I didn't include the code that pulls the data from the database since that works just fine.

HTML (to define the grid):

```
<ag-grid-angular
   #eventsGrid2
   style="width: 1200px; height:300px;"
   class="ag-theme-balham"
   [rowData]="myEventsGrid"
   [columnDefs]="eventsCols"
   (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

JS:

```
export class DataVis {
  @ViewChild('eventsGrid2') eventsGridComponent2: agGridNg2;
  selectedRows = [];
  eventsCols = [
    {headerName: '', field: 'colorId', colId: 'colorId'},
    {headerName: 'Id', field: 'id'},
    {headerName: 'File Id', cellClass: this.setColor.bind(this), field: 'fileId'}
  ]

  setColor(params) {
    this.selectedRows = [];
    this.eventsGridComponent2.api.forEachNode(node => this.selectedRows.push(node.data));
    console.log("SelectedRows:"+JSON.stringify(this.selectedRows));
    //I can see that it printed out the rows that show up in the grid
    this.selectedRows.forEach(function(element) {
      if(element.fileId == "1") {
         //trying to set the cellStyle in case that would work
         element.cellStyle = 'blue';
         //returning color to calling function
         return 'blue';
      } else {
         return 'red';
      }
      return 'green';

  }
}
```

If I put log statements in the color block I can see it hit blue where it should be `blue` and red where it should be `red`. However, it only logs out once for green but all rows in that column are now `green`! If I remove the return of `green` all rows are white background - no color.
After the cellStyle change I tried this in case it needed to be refreshed:

```
element.cellStyle = 'blue';
this.eventsGridComponent2.api.redrawRows();
```

But it returned the following error:

`Error: ag-grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows. Your code probably called a grid API method while the grid was in the render stage. To overcome this, put the API call into a timeout`

I tried the timeout it suggested but that didn't seem to work.

I would have thought returning the colors where I return them would have worked, like it does for `green`... but I guess not.

Anyone have any thoughts?

I have created a Stackblitz to try and show what I am trying to do. I coudnt get my data to show up so I just forked another project...but it still shows what I am trying to do.  In this case, I want `Colombia` to show up in `blue` - everything else red.  However, it appears to loop through `Colombia` for every row and still doesnt set it to `blue`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-template-renderer-example-3anbbx

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz with the provided code?

Comment: cellClass adds new classes but doesn't remove old ones. This may cause weird behavior. Try using 'cellClassRules' instead. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/

Comment: You are binding `cellClass` function and trying to manipulate with multiple cells, but you have to care only for used one. Btw, not fully got what you are trying to achieve, dynamically change colours by selecting cells or rows? and yes, if you will provide a full code base via stackblits or plinkr it will help everyone to help you.

Comment: You guys are awesome! I had never created a Stackblitz before... but after doing so, it allowed me to make changes and test things so much easier than to have to rebuild in my current project. Because of this, I was able to solve the problem! It is contained in above Stackblitz...but I will post solution below. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working solution is in the Stackblitz in the question but here is what did it. Instead of looping through the rows in the grid and trying to grab what I thought I needed, I just used the params coming in from the grid itself.

ColDefs:

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([
      {headerName: '', field: 'colorId', colId: 'colorId', checkboxSelection: true, cellStyle: this.cellStyling},
```

Function:

```
cellStyling(params:any){   
   if (params.data.country == 'Colombia') {
     return {'background-color': 'blue'};
    } else {
         return {'background-color': 'green'};
   }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to update columnDef / access api to update cellStyling after each keystroke?