# Change background color of certain cell header in ag-grid Angular dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag grid with the following columns. My requirement is based on the loggedin user role I want to highlight the background color of the columns `'abc'`. If the user role is admin then need to change the background-color to green of the column `'abc'`. If the role is normal user then I have to change the color to red.

```
colDefs=[
    abc: {
        headerName: 'ABC',
        field: 'abc',
        colId: 'abc',
        pinned: 'left',
      },
      def:{
        headerName: 'DEF',
        field: 'def',
        colId: 'def',
        pinned: 'left',
      },
     ghi:{
        headerName: 'GHI',
        field: 'ghi',
        colId: 'ghi',
      },
      pqr:{
        headerName: 'PQR',
        field: 'pqr',
        colId: 'pqr',
        editable: false,
      }
]

<ag-grid-angular
  #grid
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

Could you please tell me how can I implement that?
I tried following the already asked questions but didnt get the results
[Dynamic change of cell color with Ag Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55146132/dynamic-change-of-cell-color-with-ag-grid)

Also is there any way to add condition to headerName like following?

```
 headerName: isAdmin ? 'GHI' : 'XYZ',
```

Comment: you have to use custom header component to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `cellClass` and `cellStyle` as described in documentation:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-styles/

```
 {
      headerName: 'header name',
      field: 'abc',
      cellClass: params => {
          return params.value === 'something' ? 'my-class-1' : 'my-class-2';
      },
 },
```

Comment: Actually I cant. I have to highlight based on user Roles. Which is available in the component file

Comment: do you mean: cellClass: this.userRole === 'Admin' ? 'green-class': 'red-class'  ?

Comment: Yes like that. Actually headerClass.

Comment: The user role is available only in components

Comment: `this.userRole` came from component. also component's `this` will be available if you use `=>` to create function like `(params) => {
          return this.userRole === 'Admin' ? 'my-class-1' : 'my-class-2';
      },`

Comment: Object is possibly 'undefined'. while accessing this.

Comment: use `()=> {}` type function as I mentioned in comments or bind function like `this.myFunction.bind(this)` in component constructor to have `this` in the function. or search for how to bind `this` in ag-grid functions.